# What instruments help me receive a premium?

Tags: options, portfolio-management, quant-trading-strategies, risk-management, option-strategies

Apart from selling options , what other instruments can I trade(sell) to collect a premium ? The main problem that I face is as follows :

I am buying a Call option which I would like to fund by selling something else . I want to avoid selling an option in the same underlying or a correlated underlying . A solution to this would be to go for Commodity or Currency options (since the call option I am buying is in Equity markets) . Apart from options is there any other instrument that can be sold to collect the premium (to fund the call) ?

Comment: Bonds, equities, CDS, ...

Comment: Funding the purchase of one option by selling another is a nice way to end up getting nice and hurt - take [PRDCs](https://ftalphaville.ft.com/2011/03/17/518081/prcs-the-30-year-swap-spread-and-japan/), for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, generally speaking only options has time premium. I strongly advise you to avoid mixing 2 positions (short 1 option, long another one) in your mind just because they are independent, so just consider each leg as an independent trade which should be profitable by itself, without other legs.